# String split with two single quotes

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, string, split

I have a bare string where each word is separated by a comma between two single quotes.

```
Dim str As String = "a','b','c','d','e"
```

I want to split the string using `','` so that I have an array as follows:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

My code is as follows:

```
str.Split("','")
```

The array that is returned is `["a", ",", "b", ",", "c", ",", "d", ",", "e"]`.

I didn't expect this behaviour and am looking for an explanation of how the string is being split.

Comment: In C# terms, `var parts = str.Split(new string[] { "','" }, StringSplitOptions.None);` works fine... interestingly, there is no `String.Split(String)` overload - I wonder what you're hitting...

Comment: i think you missed out a single quote in `b',c`

Comment: @MarcGravell - Option Strict is Off so the Split is using the first char of the string which is `'`

Comment: @MattWilko seriously? VB does that? (shakes head in a deeply judgmental way...)

Comment: @MarcGravell - Seriously - That's why Option Strict should be on by default. This is a poor decision/oversight by MS

Comment: @MattWilko "backwards compatibility"

Comment: @MarcGravell - the thing is that MS have dropped things like the Interop Forms Toolkit and the VB6 Upgrade Wizard, so there is no need to have this Off by default anymore - it causes more problems than it fixes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the unexpected result is the fact that you are passing a String as the argument to `Split`.

There is no such overload of `Split` that accepts a String so because you have Option Strict off, the compiler uses the `Split(Char)` overload, taking only the first character in the string. So in your case

```
String.Split("','")
```

is the same as

```
String.Split("'")
```

You want to switch Option Strict On, then your code will not compile (this is a good thing because it avoids mistakes like this).

To achieve what you want, you have to pass an array of strings into the method (in this case an array containing just one string):

```
    Dim input As String = "a','b','c','d','e"
    Dim splitChars() As String = {"','"}
    Dim output As String() = input.Split(splitChars, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Comment: I was with you until the last line; IMO, the OP clearly wants to split on `"','"`, so it should use the overload that accepts a `String[]` (and the enum)

Comment: @MarcGravell - updated my answer to hopefully make this clearer

Comment: @MattWilko I'm getting two empty strings in between two alphabets. For example, output[0] = "a", output[1] = "", output[2] = "", output[3] = "b" and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need regex, you can use `Split(","c)` and remove all `'` with `String.Trim`:

```
Dim result = str.Split(","c).Select(Function(s) s.Trim("'"c)).ToArray()
```

Result: `a,b,c,d,e`

Side-note: with `Option Strict` to `Off` `Split("','")` splits only by the first character and not by the whole sub-string. If you want that you need to use the overload of [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example(note that `{"','"}` is a `string()`):

```
str.Split({"','"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

With `Option Strict On` that would not even have compiled, which is a good thing because there is no overload. So i recommend to set `Option Strict` to `On` by default. You'll learn a lot about the framework and the .NET types by fixing the compiler errors. You'll also learn to write more robust code in that way.

Comment: That is doing a split just on the comma; that may or may not be valid - it depends on the other contents of the *actual* strings.

Comment: @MarcGravell: i don't know the rest. But OP's requirement is a little bit odd since already the little sample contains invalid data according to his requirement(_"each word is separated by a comma between two single quotes"_ --> `,c',`). So imho the "correct" answer would not return the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without regex. Try this:

```
    Dim str As String = "a','b','c','d','e" 'note that ',c was changed to ','c

    Dim seperator() As String = New String() {"','"}
    Dim result() As String = str.Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

I've tried this with c# with this code:

```
string source = "a','b','c','d','e";
var seperator = new string[] {"','"};
var result = source.Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

and then converted this via http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/, so the vb.net syntax might be sketchy.

Result:

[image: Image from LinqPad]

Comment: @dbasnett Thank you for the improvement. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Its Working Well, Try it...

```
   Note: Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

  Public Shared Function SplitStr(ByVal List As String) As String

    Dim col As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(List, "'(.*?)'")
    Dim newList As String = ""

    For Each m As Match In col
        Dim g As Group = m.Groups(1)
        If newList = "" Then
            newList = g.Value
        Else
            newList += "," & g.Value
        End If
    Next
    Return newList
End Function
```